# How do I Import a manually mocked module with mocked data using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, module, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

My test doesn't seem to importing my manual mock under `__mocks__/Auth.js`.

I have a module that I use, `Auth.js` in my react application, `App.js`. I am trying to mock that module using a manual mock by making a mocked file under `__mocks__/Auth.js`. My `__mocks__` is at the same file level as `App.js` and `Auth.js`.

I have a repo here: https://github.com/chaselw/reactTesting

Or my test is below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import App from './App';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });

test('logged in false', () => {
    jest.mock('./Auth.js'); //Trying to get `auth.isLoggedIn() === false`
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.exists("[data-test='Logged-In-False']")).toBe(true);
})
```

Expected result is that the test would return a "Logged-In-False" div from Login module after the if check on `auth.isLoggedIn()`. However I get the "true" div back. 
In the test if I do: `console.log(wrapper.auth.isLoggedIn())`, it returns `.isLoggedIn()` is undefined.

I am new to React, jest and enzyme. I have no idea what is wrong, any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. `jest.mock('./Auth.js')` needs to be not inside a test, but rather at the top level as the imports.

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import EnzymeAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import App from './App';
jest.mock('./Auth');

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new EnzymeAdapter() });

test('logged in false', () => {
    //Trying to get `auth.isLoggedIn() === false`
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper.exists("[data-test='Logged-In-False']")).toBe(true);
})
```